# MVC: Trigger loading GIF when controller is processing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I got a loading gif feature in my ajax call. In all ajax call, I can trigger the loading gif.

But I want the loading gif to be triggered when I trigger a process in a controller too. The controller function is not being triggered by ajax call so my loading gif is not showing.

Is there any way I can trigger loading gif when controller is processing?

Answer (score 0):

### short answer

without using ajax, impossible

### long answer

there is really two way of calling backend controller to do something:
1. via browser post or get
2. via ajax

if it is done by method 1, this means the browser **is refreshing** the whole page with content via get or post - unless the controller is done, nothing will be displayed (hence browser display a whit page while keep spinning)
with method 2, page is not refreshing, hence need the loading icon to indicate something is happening.

So because method 1 will refresh whole page, until it is done, the browser will be waiting from controller response, hence not possible to display anything including loading giff.

Because you did not say what you need it for, I am making assumbtion that you wanted to load something, when done show the content
If so, you could initiate the task with ajax, when finish save the result into a session or somewhere similar then redirect to that page where that contoller just get the model from session then pass to view